# In the stripe invoice.payment_succeeded webhook, how can I distinguish between a subscription creation and renewal

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

According to the docs, invoice.payment_succeeded is fired both on subscription creation and on renewal.  https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle

I need different logic for the creation case and the renewal case. What in the data will I be able to use to distinguish between these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several simpler ways of doing this, since the webhook data includes the invoice information fields in the body of the data [depends on language/library you are using to get this out]:

1. Get the `billing_reason string` and check if it is `manual` or `created. subscription_cycle/subscription_update`. This would mean it is, respectively, a charge or a subscription invoice.

> Indicates the reason why the invoice was created. subscription_cycle
>   indicates an invoice created by a subscription advancing into a new
>   period. subscription_update indicates an invoice created due to
>   creating or updating a subscription. subscription is set for all old
>   invoices to indicate either a change to a subscription or a period
>   advancement. manual is set for all invoices unrelated to a
>   subscription (for example: created via the invoice editor). The
>   upcoming value is reserved for simulated invoices per the upcoming
>   invoice endpoint.

2. Check the `subscription` field on the invoice. If it is null/empty, then it is not a subscription charge. If it has a subscription field, then you can get all the other information you need with an API call.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following model to keep track of the payments:

- User has 0..1 Subscription
- Subscription has 0..* SubscriptionPayments
- SubscriptionPayment stores all relevant info coming from Stripe

When I first create the subscription using Stripe's Customer.create, I create a SubscriptionPayment object and attach it to the Subscription. At this point, the StripeInvoiceId property on Subscription payment is null (since it isn't returned from Customer.create).

Moments later, when the invoice.payment_succeeded event is fired, I retrieve the latest SubscriptionPurchase and inspect the StripeInvoiceId property.

If it is null, I know that this is an augmentation of the initial purchase, and I just update that existing object with the info that comes with the event.

The other scenario is that the latest SubscriptionPurchase already has its StripeInvoiceId property set; and in that case I know that I am dealing with a renewal.